# Resizing height & width in percentage not pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery plugin for resizing the elements. Elements height & width is set in percentage (%) not in pixel. Whenever i re-size any element it's height & width changes to pixels which is fixed but i wanted this change in percentage.

I am sure there must be some technical issue for this but there would be solution too.

```
#parentDiv { height:100%; width:100%;}

.image { height: 25%; width: 25%; }  

<body>
<div id = "parentDiv">
    <div class="image" id="image1" onmouseover="resizeMe(this);"> </div>
    <div class="image" id="image2" onmouseover="resizeMe(this);"> </div>
</div>  

<script> 
  function resizeMe(obj) {
        $(#obj.id).resizable();  }

</body>
```

But once i re-size id=image1, below is HTML code. it contains the height & width size in pixels. Does anybody light on it, How can i manage to re-size in percentage only.

```
<div class="image" style="width: 345px; height: 52px;">
```

Comment: first `$("#"+obj.id).resizable()`

Comment: oh yes, i forget to write. my silly mistake :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

jQuery gets its values from the browsers DOM engine, which always return normalized values in pixels no matter how they were intially set.

So the only way you will be able to do this is by recalculating the percentages based on elements width/height and parents width/height once the resizing has stopped.

```
$(".image").resizable({
    autoHide: true,
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        var parent = ui.element.parent();
        ui.element.css({
            width: ui.element.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
            height: ui.element.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
        });
    }
});
```

See the above [in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/xC87j/)

Notice how I'm setting the width/height with [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of using [`.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/). This is because the latter will be normalized by the DOM engine and turned into pixels.

Now to some feedback on your code. It's quite a mess to be honest. It's a really bad practice to use inline styling and scripts. Set the width/height of `#parentDiv` with css just as you did with `.image`. And don't use `onmouseover` attribute. Instead bind the event with jQuery using [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Also you shouldn't make the elements resizable on mouse over. It should be done once, when the document is ready. Use the `autoHide` option to hide the handlers while the mouse isn't over the element. An alternative is to bind `enable` and `disable` methods to mouse hover, but that will not have the same result.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I'll take care of your worthy suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus, importantly, this also works very good with `<img>` tags as well as `<div>`. The `<img>` is better than the `<div>` b/c `resizable()` then rescales the image whereas with the `<div>` it simply shifts what part of the `background-image` that is shown. Compare the 1st and 3rd boxes in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/xC87j/97/).